# XAML - Use different template based on class

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a nested datagrid. The grid is bound to a EquipmentListViewModel, which then contains a list of EquipmentViewModels. Each row can be dropped down by clicking a  "+" button which will display a list of Frequencies for that equipment. I want to be able to display different RowDetailsTemplates depending on the CLASS of the row. The following is an example of what I want to do:

```
 -BaseClass(Hit + button to dropdown equipment list below)
   -EquipmentTypeA(Should have a + button to drop down, is of class "TypeA")
       -Frequencies
   -EquipmentTypeB(Doesnt contain a + buton, so it is different than EquipmentTypeA, of class "TypeB")
```

How can I have BaseClass contain a list of EquipmentTypes, where each row implements a derived class from the EquipmentTypes base class(TypeA,TypeB,etc). This way I can have each row have custom code depending on its class type(if it should contain a button, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying `RowDetailsTemplates` explicitly, just make sure that the visual tree contains a `DataTemplate` for each class (`EquipmentTypeA` and `EquipmentTypeB`) you wish to display.  These will get used by default if the template is not specified.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.I am still new to WPF:( Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do I just use a normal <DataTemplate>? Or is there a datagrid specific one I am not seeing.